# case details are not getting populated in Email template

Tags: apex, trigger, email-template

I am using template in Apex class.Email template containing case details.
In apex class i am able to send mail to user but data is not coming in email tamplate (like case number)

```
for(case cs:caselist){
    for(Id id : caseQueueNameMap.keySet()){

        List<String> sendToAdresses = new List<String>();
        List<Id> userIdList =  queueWiseGroupUsers.get(caseQueueNameMap.get(id));

        System.debug('caseQueueNameMap.keySet()---->'+caseQueueNameMap.keySet());
        System.debug('userIdList------>'+userIdList);

        if(userIdList != null){
            for(Id uid : userIdList){
                if(queueMembers != null && !queueMembers.isEmpty() && queueMembers.containsKey(uid)) {

                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    //sendToAdresses.add(queueMembers.get(uid).Email);
                    //System.debug('sendToAdresses---->'+sendToAdresses);
                    mail.setTemplateId('00X28000000MuM4EAK');
                    mail.setsaveAsActivity(false);
                    mail.setWhatId(cs.id);
                    mail.setTargetObjectId(uid);
                    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});  
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> {System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, WhatId is not available for sending emails to UserIds.: [whatId, 5002800000JqkLN]:}

Comment: Hi Ajay,
You setWhatId method. In this whatId contains you wanted task details taskId



**Example:** `mail.setWhatId(taskId)`

Comment: Thanks for reply.How can i get CaseId in setWhatId.   As i need to display case details in email template

Comment: caseQueueNameMap keyset is caseId or not?

Comment: check my updated piece of code.I have added the case loop in start.....I am getting below error    {ystem.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, WhatId is not available for sending emails to UserIds.: [whatId, 5002800000JqkLN]:}

Comment: How to construct your emailtemplate? VF or HTML email template.